# Is it possible to get a circle of colors from a CD on a wall with artificial light?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, diffraction

A CD acts as a diffraction grating and a circle of colors can be seen in a wall using the sun as a source of light.

[image]

However I tried several types of lamps (incandescent, fluorescent and LED's) and could not produce the same effect. The iridescence can be seen on the CD surface, but not on the wall.

One of the lamps has an information about an equivalent temperature of more that 6000 K, what would be a "little sun", but nothing of color circle on the wall.

I think that it is related to the intensity of the light (it works for the sun only if it is totally free of clouds). Is it right?

Another related question: Could the effect be produced by an electric arc of an welding electrode?

Comment: I believe the difference is that light from the Sun is parallel

Comment: @CharlesFrancis I got the circular rainbow from the car headlight. Maybe the reflecting system behind the lamp helps to concentrate all radiation in one direction.

Comment: Yes. Headlights are designed to direct light as far up the road as possible in a near parallel beam.

Answer (score 1):

The light diffracted from a CD spreads very rapidly.  If you can illuminate the CD using a very small light source that it *at* a white wall, with the CD a couple of feet away from a white wall, it should form a circular rainbow on the wall.  It will be important to prevent any light from the source from hitting the wall directly: the white wall should appear as dark as possible so the only light hitting the wall is diffracted from the CD.

There should be two rainbows, corresponding to the positive and negative diffracted orders.  The negative orders should come to a fuzzy focus between the light source and the CD, then spread out to a rainbow having smaller diameter on the wall than the positive order rainbow.